# Solution of following integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I have this integration as a homework and the result supposed to be $1/5$ but I cannot find the result. I have tried integration by parts but could not be able to simplify the equation. A little help would be great.

### $$\int_{0}^{5}\left(\frac{1}{55}\right) \frac{e^{-x}x^{n}}{n!}dx$$

Comment: Are you sure about the integrand ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pull out the constants $1/55$ and $1/n!$ to start with, so they don't get in your way. Then execute the integration by parts

$$\int e^{-t} t^n\,dt = -e^{-t}t^n + n\int e^{-t}t^{n-1}\, dt$$

over and over until you have no more powers of $t$ in the integrand.

When I solve the integral I get

$$\frac{1}{55}\left(1 - e^{-5} - 5e^{-5} - \frac{1}{2!}5^2e^{-5} - \frac{1}{3!}5^3e^{-5} - \dotsb - \frac{1}{n!}5^ne^{-5} \right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{55} - \frac{1}{55}e^{-5}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{5^k}{k!}\right),$$

which has limit zero since $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{5^n}{n!}=e^5$. It's possible I made an arithmetic error in there somewhere, but you get the general idea.

Comment: yeah I tried exactly the same but couldnt find the result. The part that go out of integration is not zero in my calculations so i think that does not work. but maybe I made some error in calculations.  I mean there is a exponential term that survives in every derivative with respect to x you take.

Comment: I think that there is something wrong in this problem. The result is a decreasing function of $x$ and its maximum value is $\frac{e^5-1}{55 e^5}\approx  0.0180593$ for $x=0$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $x$ is a constant here, somewhat confusingly

Comment: I know and this is why I made this comment.

Comment: @halfmetal If you're taking derivatives with respect to $x$, then that is your problem. Since you're integrating with respect to $a$, you should be treating $x$ as a constant. Try replacing $x$ with $n$ to make things look more clear.

Comment: maybe ı should edit the equation and change the variables that would make it clear

Comment: @halfmetal You might want to change $a$ to $x$ or $t$, since $a$ is typically taken to be a constant.

Comment: @EricAuld when exactly would you stop using integration by parts. There is no limit. I believe another alternative should be sought

Comment: ıf you do intergration by parts for once you'll get $$-e^{-5}5^{n}+\int_{0}^{5}e^{-x}nx^{n-1}dx$$ I omitted the constants as you can see those exponential terms wont cancel

Comment: @VarunIyer You stop after $n$ times of doing so. Recall that $n$ is a constant. No limit necessary.

Comment: @EricAuld i see that now

Comment: @halfmetal Look at Claude's answer above, where he claims that the answer cannot be 1/5. You will get a series of $n$ terms, and you may be able to get the series to simplify, though, if you do some arithmetic.

Comment: @EricAuld I figured there will be some arithmetic trick that can solve this but ı couldnt find it. Thats why I asked the question.

Comment: @halfmetal Edited my answer.

Comment: @EricAuld I see. But still we dont get the result $1/5$ right?

Comment: @halfmetal Not as far as I can tell.